# PHP: A better way of getting the first value in an array if it's present

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
$quizId = '';
foreach ($module['QuizListing'] as $quizListing)    {
    if ($quizListing['id']) {
        $quizId = $quizListing['id'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @baker: `$module['QuizListing']` is coming from some `SQL` query ?

Comment: Better use `isset` to avoid warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is reasonable assuming that:

- multiple quiz listings appear; and
- not all of them have an ID.

I assume from your question that one of both of these is not true. If you want the first quiz listing then do this:

```
$listing = reset($module['quizListing']);
$quizId = $listing['id'];
```

The [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function returns the first element in the array (or `false` if there isn't one).

This assumes every quiz listing has an ID. If that's not the case then you can't get much better than what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Slight change:

```
$quizId = '';
foreach ($module['QuizListing'] as $quizListing)    {
    if (isset($quizListing['id'])) {
        $quizId = $quizListing['id'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to answer if this array is coming from a database you probably have to better to filter your query not to include those row at first place

something like

```
SELECT * from Quiz WHERE id <> 0
```

this would give you an array usable without any other processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$quiz = array_shift($module['QuizListing']);

if (null != $quiz) {
    echo "let's go";
}
```

Comment: Note that `array_shift(...)` will modify the input array.

Answer (score 1):

Using array_key_exists you can check if the key exists for your array. If it exists, then assign it to whatever you want.

```
if (array_key_exists('id', $quizListing)) {
  $quizId = $quizListing['id'];   
}
```